# How can I fix bugged Google Play store links in Android?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

On Android, when an app is intending to send you to it's own store page to update the app manually, or to view other apps from the same publisher, the system is supposed to seamlessly open the Google Play store. However about a month ago I started having an issue, and apparently I'm not the only one. There are numerous reports of this online, when you might try to tap a link to the play store from within an app or game, you'll get an error that says "please install and set up a web-viewing client". The generally agreed-upon answer I've found is to find the setting for default apps, and set Google Play to "ask every time" rather than the default, which automatically allows Google Play to open two domains,  play.google.com and market.android.com links. The outcome on my phone seems to be different than everyone else.

I did the aforementioned step, setting the Google Play app's behavior to "ask every time" when attempting to open Google Play links. Instead of it asking me anything, when I tap a relevant link within an app, it opens the Google Play store app which then immediately opens my web browser instead. This is undesireable because the web version does not directly have access to my storage or see what I have installed. There are janky workarounds, but I want to know how to fix this behavior.

If an app is requesting a manual update and has a button labeled 'update', I can see from my browser's URL that the button is supposed to send me to that app's Google Play store page so that I can manually update. I would like to know how to make these links work correctly again.